# Using Selenium-specific apis in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, integration-testing, capybara

Can someone describe exactly how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just refer to the browser object from `page.driver`.

One example from my tests:

```
page.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
```